# Заполнение двумерного списка Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно сделать двумерный список n*n с числами которые увеличиваются вдвое (1,2,4,8,16 и тд) и выводить то число по координатам введенным пользователем,я сделал генератор списков,но вывести не могу.

```
n=int(input())
s=int(input())
g=int(input())
a = [[0]*n for i in range(n)]
counter = 1
for x in range(n):
    for y in range(n):
        a[x][y] = counter
        counter += counter
print(a)

print(a[s][g])
```

Входные данные:

```
8 2 7
```

8- длина поля
2 , 7 - координаты соответственно 
Выходные:

```
32768
```

у меня выводит:8388608
я понимаю что счет введется с 0 но я не могу додуматься как нормально вывести

Comment: `print(a[s-1][g-1])` ? Кстати правильный вывод должен быть: `16384`

Comment: я пробовал, но вывод должен быть 32768,в задаче написано

Comment: хотя возможно опечатка

Comment: значит вы неправильно заполняете массив - начинайте заполнение с `1`, а не с `0`

Comment: я с 1 и заполняю,проверьте код

Comment: если исходить из того, что матрица заполнена правильно, то правильный ответ: `print(a[s-1][g-1])`

Comment: я разобрался,в задаче указано что строка отсчитывается с 0,а столбцы с 1

Comment: `range` возвращает значения от 0 до 7, а вы наверное представляете массив, как от 1 до 8, поэтому вам верно возвращается значение 8388608, так как в написанном коде, по вашему пониманию вы выводите 3 строку, 8 столбец

Answer (score 1):

`print(a[s - 1][g - 1])` - если сделать такой вывод, то ваш ввод (8, 2, 7) даст вывод 16384. А то, что Вы ввели выдает такой результат по очевидной причине. Ведь счет начинается с 0, следовательно задавая s = 2 - это все равно как обратится к третьему списку. Поэтому у вас и вывод такой. Если используете такой вывод `print(a[s - 1][g - 1])`, а входные данные (8,2,8), то и получите требуемый результат. В вашем же случае задавайте входные данные следующие (8, 1, 7).

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы все вышло нужно чуток подправить здесь:

```
print(a[s-1][g])

#Ввожу
#8
#2
#7

#Получаю
#32768
```